# Attempting Background Refresh

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to execute code in the background of my app using this code in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  if let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController {
    print("done")
    viewController.updateUI(weather: "cloudy", temp: 67.0)
  }
}
```

However, the code within the if let statement does not run, and nothing is printed. I already have enabled Background fetch, and trigger the refresh through a background scheme.

How can I get my code within the if let statement to run?

Comment: have you tried adding in an 'else' after the if ?

Comment: Also note that you *must* call the `completionHandler`

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, when you're launched from the background your UI will not yet exist. You should not be trying to communicate with a view controller in the background; they're not on screen. Your model objects should take care of data. Your view controllers should just display it.

Comment: I don't think it's an error with the function calling while not on screen, but rather that all code within the "if let" does not run.

Comment: @rohan I agree. But the underlying problem is that the UI is not there yet because the app is in the background. The if-let doesn't run *because* the view controller is not on the screen.